# Is there any way to write two token issuer Technical profile in AD B2C Custom policy?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

As my policy is accessed by both mobile and web apps, the token lifetime is different for mobile from web and i want to use the same policies for both. So is there any way to write two separate TP for token issuing for mobile and web. Or is there any other way to handle without two TPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need one relying party section configured for web and another configured for your mobile app. 2 separate files both pointing to the same base policy.

Comment: Thanks, I have plan like will write 2 TP one for mobile and one for web and by determining a query string parameter will decide in user journey which TP for JWT will work, does that wok and is there any issues in that?

Comment: It depends, you can use query parameters to control the orchestration steps, but generally you should have one Relying Party section per Application. And that each RP section would have its own Technical Profile that defines the claims which are sent to the application.